# Separate navigation menu from default.ctp in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

I am working on CakePHP 2.7. I have to show some static menu on every page. Since, the menu contains lot of sub menus, I want to keep them in a separate file `navigation.ctp` and show them on `default.ctp`

I tried extend and elements but none of them give expected result.

***Note*** : This is not dynamic menu and I am not fetching them from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your navigation.ctp inside app/View/Elements/

Then, inside your default.ctp, include the element as follows:

```
<?= $this->element('navigation'); ?>
```

Note that if you need any variables within the element, you may need to pass them through inside an array as a second parameter, such as:

```
<?= $this->element('navigation', array(
    "varible_name" => "variable_value"
    )); ?>
```